# Zend Framework 2: Dynamic navigation and breadcrumbs

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route

I made a navigation in Zend Framework 2 using a global file located in `config/autoload`. how can I get in this global file the route parameters?

I have tried this:

```
$helper = new Zend\View\Helper\ServerUrl();
$active_url = $helper->getHost();
```

but this returns the whole url.
For exemle I have an url like this

```
www.mysite.com/controller/action/id/3
```

I need to know the id.

My global file return a navigation array that looks like this:

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label'      => 'Home',
                'route'      => 'admin',
                'active'     => true,
                'resource'   => 'Admin\Controller\Index',
                'privilege' => 'index',
                'pages'     =>  array(
                    'label'  => 'My posts ',
                    'route'  => 'admin/default',
                    'params' => array(
                        'controller' => 'posts',
                        'action' => 'edit'
                    ),
                    'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Posts',
                    'privilege' => 'edit',
                ),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

It all work fine as long as the route doesn't contain parameters. If my url contain an ID parameters my menu link and the breadcrumbs are form just with the controller and action without ID and in the same.

So, instead of:

```
www.mysite.com/posts/edit/id/12
```

My link looks like:

```
www.mysite.com/posts/edit
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Global and local files in the `config/autoload` folder should **only** be used for declaring constants, not for dynamic content. You will get into trouble if you do this. It is hard to give an alternative solution if you don't add some more details on what exactly you are trying to achieve...

Comment: The config is loaded before routing happens. You're not going to be able to do this.

Comment: @Wilt I edited my post.

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks, I'll try to find another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is dynamic breadcrumbs. It is not so common to tie breadcrumbs to route params, but you can find a question with an answer [here on stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350589/zf2-navigation-breadcrumbs-paging).

As also written in [the documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.navigation.pages.html#zend-navigation-page-mvc) there is since ZF2 version 2.2.0 a `'useRouteMatch'` flag that you can set to `true`.

> Starting in version 2.2.0, if you want to re-use any matched route parameters when generating a link, you can do so via the “useRouteMatch” flag. This is particularly useful when creating segment routes that include the currently selected language or locale as an initial segment, as it ensures the links generated all include the matched value.

Instead of manually passing your `params` arary the navigator will use the `params` from the `RouteMatch`. Thus you will have your id also available.

```
array(
    'label' => 'My posts',
    'route' => 'admin/default',
    'useRouteMatch' => true
),
```

---

**Note** You said you defined your navigation in a `global` file in the `autoload/config` folder. It would be better to implement the navigation in your `module.config.php` as shown [here in this tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/tutorial.navigation.html#configuring-our-site-map).